# Adding a comment to a task in Jira software

Tags: jira-agile

At the bottom of the task, under Activity, I am seeing All, Comments, Work Log, History and Activity. I selected the Comments tab. However, I don't see a way to add a comment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you could attach a screenshot of what you saw in your page it would help other to give advices.

Answer (score 0):

The Comments button which you are talking about shows all the comments. There is a Comment button with an icon just below the Activity tab which can be used to comment on the tasks as shown in the pic
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8stz7.png).

Comment: There is no Comments button. Under Activity, All, Comments, Work Log, History and Activity are all tabs. I saw your pic. I don't have that button there. There is already an existing comment on the task. I want to add another one.

Comment: Try to minimize the Activity button from the arrow on the left. I also have some comments but I am able to add another comment.

Comment: Here is what I have. How do I add a comment here?: https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMOfzjcjT_LRFZg8cCuMkQQ_Snhho0w5SmFWdrM

Comment: I am not able to access the photo

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permissions issue. If you do not have permission to add comments on a project then you will not see the button for adding a comment.

Confirm with your JIRA administrator that you have the "Add comments permission" for this particular project (or for all projects).